# ¿Cómo realizar el promedio de notas mediante Java?

Tags: java

Tengo este código, pero no me da el promedio, estoy aprendiendo y me gustaría saber que estoy realizando mal:

```
        Scanner leer =  new Scanner(System.in);
        int notas;

        System.out.print("ingrese cantidad de notas:");
        notas = leer.nextInt();

        for(int i=1; i<= notas; i++){
            System.out.println("ingrese nota"+" "+i+" "+"de"+" "+notas+":");

            int nota = leer.nextInt();  
            int suma = 0;
            int prom = 0;         
            suma = suma + i;
            prom= prom + suma /notas;
            System.out.println("promedio de las notas:"+prom );

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Tengo este codigo, pero no me da el promedio, me gustaria saber en que estoy mal, estoy aprendiendo recien, muchas gracias

Comment: La variable "prom" debería estar fuera del bucle for, para que divida el valor de la suma total para obtener el promedio. Y la variable suma debería ir aumentando con el input que lee de la variable "nota" en lugar del contador "i"

Comment: Ya genial muchas gracias, me resulto :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo dentro del bucle es su propio mundo hasta que se termine, así que hay detalles que se deben tomar en cuenta:

```
for(int i=1; i<= notas; i++){
    System.out.println("ingrese nota"+" "+i+" "+"de"+" "+notas+":");
  int nota = leer.nextInt();
```

**En la parte inicial estás solicitando un bucle que se repita dependiendo de la cantidad de notas desea ingresar el profesor, por cada nota hace una iteracción y la guarda en la variable nota**

---

```
    int suma = 0;
    int prom = 0;
```

**Despúes de capturar la calificación, le asignas el valor "0" a las variables suma y prom, esto se debe realizar fuera del bucle sino en cada iteración se borraran los valores en estos almacenadores**

---

```
    suma = suma + i;
```

**Aquí deberías ir acumulando los valores de cada nota: Ej: 10+8+5+10 por lo que el valor que se debría capturar sería "nota"**

---

```
    prom= prom + suma /notas;
    System.out.println("promedio de las notas:"+prom );
```

**Esto debería ir fuera del bucle, ya que el promedio lo obtienes al final de haber capturado todas las notas y solo ahí se presenta**

---

Podría ser algo así:

```
Scanner leer =  new Scanner(System.in);
        int notas;
        int suma = 0;
        int prom = 0;         

 System.out.print("ingrese cantidad de notas:");
        notas = leer.nextInt();

        for(int i=1; i<= notas; i++){
            System.out.println("ingrese nota"+" "+i+" "+"de"+" "+notas+":");
            int nota = leer.nextInt();  
            suma = suma + nota;
        }
            prom= suma /notas;
            System.out.println("promedio de las notas:"+prom );
    }   
}
```

No eh trabajado con java en varios años así que posiblemente se requiera alguna conversión por tipo de dato, pero no podría estar seguro.

Suerte

Comment: gracias, fue mucha ayuda !

Comment: Un gusto @AileenAravena

Answer (score 2):

Si tienes un listado de numeros (Integer, Float, Double) puedes aplicar esta función utilitaria:

```
public static double calculateAverage(List<Double> list) {
    double average = 0;
    for (Double  v : list) {
        average += v;
    }
    return !list.isEmpty() ? average/list.size() : null;
}
```

el valor de retorno por defecto lo puedes elegir tu.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías de modificar un poco tu código ya que estás inicializando todo el rato tus variables `suma` y `prom` dentro del bucle `for`, es decir, para cada iteración del bucle, a tus valores `suma` y `prom` les estás asignando el valor 0.

Para que esto no ocurra, y solo se inicialicen una vez, deberías de sacar ambas variables fuera del bucle.

Por otro lado, lo mismo ocurre a la hora de sacar el resultado del promedio, ya que lo estás realizando para cada iteración del bucle. En realidad deberías de hacerlo después cuando hayas recogido todas tus notas.

Además, no estás asignando a la suma el valor de la nota introducida para posteriormente hacer el promedio. En el caso de tu cálculo del promedio no necesitarías sumarle el promedio ya que simplemente tendrías que dividir la suma de las notas entre el total de notas introducidas.

Tu código corregido:

```
Scanner leer =  new Scanner(System.in);
int notas;

System.out.print("ingrese cantidad de notas:");
notas = leer.nextInt();

int suma = 0;
int prom = 0; 
int nota = 0;

for(int i=1; i<= notas; i++){
    System.out.println("ingrese nota"+" "+i+" "+"de"+" "+notas+":");
    nota = leer.nextInt();          
    suma = suma + nota;
}

prom = suma / notas;
System.out.println("promedio de las notas:"+prom );
```

Comment: gracias, es de mucha ayuda!

Comment: @ACAU Si esta respuesta te sirvió de ayuda, sería bueno que votaras positivo. Las respuestas con puntos suben hacia arriba y son más visibles. Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Como complemento a la respuesta de [@J.Castro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/97470/40247)

> No eh trabajado con java en varios años así que posiblemente se requiera alguna conversión por tipo de dato, pero no podría estar seguro.

El promedio debiera ser de tipo double, y habría que castear la suma para el cálculo del promedio:

```
... 
double prom = 0;
...
prom = (double)suma / notas;
```